# Replace characters with complete words depending on their position C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, stringbuilder

I have a list of incomplete band names such as

`string band1 = "ONE ..."`, `string band2 = "... 5"`, `string band3 = "30 ... ... ..."`, `string band4 = "The ... Stones"`

I need to replace the characters `...` to form the full band's name so they become

`ONE DIRECTION`, `MAROON 5`, `30 SECONDS TO MARS`, `THE ROLLING STONES`

I have the associated answer, for example the string `DIRECTION` that can be combined with `string band1 = ONE ...` to form `ONE DIRECTION`. My question is since the `...` characters may be located before or after the string `ONE`, how can I make sure to create `ONE DIRECTION` instead of `DIRECTION ONE` and so on?

Comment: does it need to be as complicated as this? wouldn't it be simplier to let the user write the whole band name?

Comment: As it's a puzzle trivia game, the user need to fill in the missing words. When the correct words are filled in, I need to show the full band name.

Answer (score 0):

use a combination of string.StartsWith, string.EndsWith and string.Length to determine the correct replacement

Comment: Unless you put some actual codes using those methods which fit the OP's concern, this is better put as a comment. You have enough reputation to do that.

Comment: The `...` could also be in the middle.

Comment: Then use string.Contains

Answer (score 0):

Try this example with your sample strings.  You will the get the idea.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string question = string.Empty;
            string answer = string.Empty;
            string formattedString = string.Empty;
            question = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Replace ... with:");
            answer = Console.ReadLine();
            formattedString = question.Replace("... ", answer);
            Console.WriteLine(formattedString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: this will fail, if the `...` are at the end of the sentence, no need to replace the space too - what's with the case of multiple `...`?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 2:**

In this solution, i'm splitting your string by `...` to an array of strings. Like this you know where `...` are placed at, no matter how many of them are around and where they are and finally merge them.

Additionally i'm working with a `Dictionary`, with this it's dynamic.

Have a look at the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> bands = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    bands.Add("30 ... ... ...", "SECONDS TO MARS");
    bands.Add("... 5", "MAROON");
    bands.Add("... STEPS ... ...", "TWO FROM HELL");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> band in bands)
    {
        bool solved = false;

        while (!solved)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("current band: " + band.Key);

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (band.Value == input.ToUpper())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct");
                string[] splittedQuestion = band.Key.Split(new string[] { "..." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                string[] splittedAnswer = band.Value.Split(' ');

                // fill splittedQuestion string with answer values
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedAnswer.Count(); i++)
                {
                    int currentIndex = GetNextDotIndex(splittedQuestion);
                    if (currentIndex != -1)
                    {
                        splittedQuestion[currentIndex] = splittedAnswer[i];
                    }
                }

                // build result
                string result = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < splittedQuestion.Count(); i++)
                {
                    result += splittedQuestion[i].Trim().ToUpper();
                    if (i < splittedQuestion.Count() - 1)
                    {
                        result += " ";
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result);
                solved = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("wrong");
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("finished");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int GetNextDotIndex(string[] splittedQuestion)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < splittedQuestion.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (splittedQuestion[j] == "" || splittedQuestion[j] == " ")
        {
            return j;
        }
    }
    // return -1, when no more ... are available
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This could work. However I'd prefer not to create a new dictionary with the correct band name `Add("30 SECONDS TO MARS"` etc. as the list can be rather long. I would prefer to combine the existing strings such as `string band1 = "ONE ..."` and `DIRECTION`

Comment: you may do this in any way. But consider, that you have to compare it with something, to check if the input value is correct

Comment: You are right. In my case, I am comparing it with the second string which is missing for instance `DIRECTION` and not the full band's name.

Comment: Ok, but in that case, is doesn't matter if `ONE` is before or after `DIRECTION`. The user have to type simply the second string, no need to know where the `...` are.

Comment: It does matter to me though because I have to display the full band's name after the correct comparison. After user enter `DIRECTION` I have to combine `ONE ...` with `DIRECTION` and so on.

Comment: @PutraKg I've updated the answer. With this you have at the end the whole band name merged.